# change animate() speed while it animates and hover over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I need to change the speed of an element animated with jQuery animate(). The speed should only change while the user hovers over a given element. Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
    var speed = 2000;

    $('li').hover(
    function(){
        var speed = 500;
    }
    );

    $(function () {
       function drive() {
         $( ".plane" ).animate({
            "left": "+=50",
          }, speed, drive);
        } 
      drive();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the global variable speed, not just setting up another local variable inside the hover'functions callback. Also note that hover will be executed twice one for hover in and another for hover out.

```
   var speed = 2000;

    $('li').hover(function(){
        speed += 500;
    });

    $(function () {
       function drive() {
         $( ".plane" ).animate({
            "left": "+=50",
          }, speed, drive);
        } 
      drive();
    });
```